# Massive Temp Files Being Generated By Application - ASP.NET MVC/IIS 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6, temporary-files

I just recently put an ASP.NET MVC application I developed/tested/etc up to my company's production server (IIS 6). However, it is generating some massive temp files (up to 1GB!), which is a problem, since the server is running a 2GB partition.

UPDATE: MORE INFO:
The temp files are being put into the c:\windows\temp directory

Is this normal behavior? If not, what possible causes could there be, and solutions.

If it is normal, what is the best way to overcome it?

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: There really isn't enough information here to help you.  Where are these temp files?  When are they generated?

Comment: I updated the post with more info. The temp files are being generated as the site is being used, still trying to isolate the situation.

Comment: Also, the site deals with uploading files to the file system, using the following syntax:

string audioFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(audioFile.FileName);

              string audioDir = @"E:\dir\www.example.com\audiofiles\";
              audioFile.SaveAs(audioDir + audioFileName);`

Comment: 1 GB is "massive?" I'd say that a 2 GB partition for your temp folder is "minuscule."

Comment: Okay, so it probably isn't a bug, then? If so, is there any other solution than doing a bigger partition?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code maybe posting/saving some of the uploaded file cache in the temp dir.

Try commenting some code out that does the upload/saving and see if it still making temp files.